# Unable to fix error DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Please help resolving this env issue/error. I did found many posts about resolving that error but I still couldn't fix mine. I guess I am just unable to understand it in the right way.

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I have just one app in my Django project, had created using django-admin startproject. The app is added to settings.py under INSTALLED_APPS, and all other settings are set to default by Django itself which i haven't modified.

I have few def in views.py working on models/forms, and those are working well.
I also have created a new folder (myscripts) in the project (next to the app-name folder), and in that myscripts folder i have my other py scripts (other than models/forms). Executing those scripts works, I am able to import those models/forms, it does some work and adds a new entry in django db sqlite3 correctly.

Further, i want to add/update execution status to the db entry (for a given pk/id) after my other scripts finishes its work.
To achieve that, I am trying a new py script which will import models to get its objects so i can update contents in the db but that fails. (throws me above error).

Based on other posts, i did try adding env variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=my-app-name.settings, it doesn't work (i just have one app and django has it already configured -- i can see that in wsgi.py as `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my-app-name.settings')`  ).

I also tried `code from django.conf import settings` , but that also with no success.

However, when I run "python manage.py shell" and import models and its objects they don't throw error but thorws error when i run the update py script.

Please guide me where i can look for to fix the issue.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage

Comment: thanks Iain for the link, i will check it right now

Comment: Hi Iain, importing django throws Attribute error `code` AttributeError: module 'visual_diff_r1.settings' has no attribute 'LOGGING_CONFIG' `code` .

visual_diff_r1 is my django project name. How can we fix that error please.

Comment: Also Iain, from that link the import line `from myapp import myapp_defaults` , my app doesn't have myapp_defaults in it. Is it mandatory to have myapp_defaults def in myapp?

Comment: I would suggest creating a custom management command instead of a stand-alone script. I tend to always go this direction because of these issues

Comment: the custom management command thing looking complex to me at this moment :-/ I still haven't grasped much of Django basics yet. I will give a try on custom then.